# Missing function "split" in the R package stars

Tags: r, r-stars

I have a problem with package `stars` when trying to use `split` function to split a `stars` raster object. I use the `stars` version 0.5-4 (that one is automatically installed when asking for installing `stars`). According to the package documentation, there should be a function `split` (in fact, it's probably a method for the generic R function `split`) for splitting `stars` object. However, when I try to use it, my R says there is no such function in the `stars` namespace. Is the function really missing and the documentation wrong? Or could that be caused by some other problem with namespaces?

```
> library(stars)
> split.stars
Error: object 'split.stars' not found
> stars::split
Error: 'split' is not an exported object from 'namespace:stars'
```

But when I type

```
> ?stars
```

I get the help for the `split` function from `stars`. Can someone explain that?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: It works now, not sure what the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) is a base R function. It’s an [S3 generic](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html), and the ‘stars’ package provides its own method implementation for a custom S3 class.

To use the method, use it as any other, regular function from base R. That is, write `split`. Don’t write `split.stars`, nor `stars::split`.

Comment: Of course, that's what I did first. And there was an error because the base method split cannot work with stars objects as arguments. The code above just demonstrated there is really no function 'split' in the stars namespace.

Comment: @VojtaBartak Hard to say what the issue is, you’ll need to post an [mcve]. It works for me (e.g. when following the [introduction](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars1.html)). Did you load the package?

Comment: Sure I loaded the package. I don't understand what happened, but it works now! Maybe I just misunderstood the previous error message. Thanks for your time and sorry for messing up.